# Error after upgrade to wordpress 3.5.1

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, fastcgi

After upgrading to wordpress 3.5.1. I have few database errors which are similar to this. How to solve this?

> 2013/04/27 18:43:32 [error] 1361#0: *1161766 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "WordPress database error Duplicate column name 'hsa_link' for query
>   ALTER TABLEwp_hsa_pluginADDhsa_linkVARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL made by
>   activate_plugin,
>   do_action('activate_horizontal-scrolling-announcement/horizontal-scrolling-announcement.php'),
>   call_user_func_array, HSA_activation, W3_Db->query" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: , server: example.com, request:
>   "GET
>   /wp-admin/plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=horizontal-scrolling-announcement%2Fhorizontal-scrolling-announcement.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=e0c9f7a949
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com",
>   referrer:
>   "http://example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?activate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the horizontal-scrolling-announcement plugin to begin with and see if you can revive the site.  If so you should be able to find the issue in a function called activate_plugin in the file:

wp-content/plugins/activate_horizontal-scrolling-announcement/horizontal-scrolling-announcement.php

It looks like its trying to add a column (hsa_link) again having added it previously.  Try changing 'Add hsa_link' to 'MODIFY hsa_link', or you can remove the SQL and do that change yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a plugin, apparently for horizontal scrolling, which apparently hasn't been tested with WP 3.5.1.

The problem is occurring when the plugin is activated. It looks to me like there's some kind of ALTER TABLE function going on, that's repeated more than once.

You'll need to uninstall the plugin until you can persuade the developer to fix it.